# Add bootstrap css class 'list-group' to Drupal facet class js-facets-checkbox-links

Tags: theming, 8, search

I want to theme the Drupal facets into the Bootstrap theme.

**1)** How do I *add* a bootstrap css-class `list-group` to the existing facet class `js-facets-checkbox-links`. So I get:

```
<ul data-drupal-facet-id="contactvoorkeur" class="list-group js-facets-checkbox-links">
```

**2)** And how do I *replace* an existing facet class `facet-item` with `list-group-item`:

```
<li class="list-group-item">
```